# How to two-way bind select element with prop in React

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, reactjs

Whats the approved way to create select element in react, which is two way bound with the prop of selection containing component? The default selection should be the present attribute of the prop (may be generated, because the value is arbitrary, and on selection the prop attribute should reflect the selection. Also, it should be possible to write the value directly to the selection field.

Comment: Can you add more specifics on your case? From your question, it's not clear what you need. Have you looked at https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#why-select-value to use it as a foundation of your custom select element?

Answer (score 4):

I add the options to an array on state and then map overthem,
try this code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class SelectExample extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      options: ['One', 'Tow', 'Three'],
      selectedOption: 'One',
    }
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <select name='selectedOption' onChange={this.handleChange}>
        {this.state.options.map(i => i == this.state.selectedOption ? (
        <option value={i} selected>
          {i}
        </option>
        ) : (<option value={i}>{i}</option>) )}
      </select>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There isn't an "approved" way as such, but you should note a couple of things:

1. The change event is triggered on the  element, not the  element.
2. [Controlled and uncontrolled components `defaultValue` are set differently](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#why-select-value).

This is a generic example of a controlled dropdown menu

```
var MyDropdown = React.createClass({
     getInitialState: function() {
         return {
             value: 'select'
         }
     },
     change: function(event){
         this.setState({value: event.target.value});
     },
     render: function(){
        return(
           <div>
               <select id="fruit" onChange={this.change} value={this.state.value}>
                  <option value="select">Select</option>
                  <option value="Apples">Apples</option>
                  <option value="Mangoes">Mangoes</option>
               </select>
               <p></p>
               <p>{this.state.value}</p>
           </div>
        );
     }
});

React.render(<MyDropdown />, document.body);
```

and here's a [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/47217/).